How to leave a mark on the texture of the walls when in contact with a physical object - a bullet?
Currently I am trying to have a bullet hole appear wherever the bullet from a player lands. Specifically on walls and the floor.
Below is my current script for shooting a gun.
private void Shoot()
{
    _audio.Stop();
    Ray ray = mainCamera.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0));
    RaycastHit hit;

    Vector3 targetPoint;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        targetPoint = hit.point;
    else
        targetPoint = ray.GetPoint(75);

    Vector3 dirWithoutSpread = targetPoint - spawnBullet.position;

    float x = Random.Range(-spread, spread);
    float y = Random.Range(-spread, spread);

    Vector3 dirWithSpread = dirWithoutSpread + new Vector3(x, y, 0);

    GameObject currentBullet = Instantiate(bullet, spawnBullet.position, Quaternion.identity);

    currentBullet.transform.forward = dirWithSpread.normalized;

    currentBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(dirWithSpread.normalized * shootForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    _audio.time = 0.15f;
    _audio.Play();
}

THE CONTACT OF OBJECTS SHOULD BE READ, NOT RAY
Whats the best way of having a bullet hole appear on a wall/floor?

I would consider the "trace" an "object" that "looks" like a divot (or whatever) and attach it at the "contact" point on the wall. You can vary properties based on where and what the bullet collided with. Not much different from any other "spot" or stain.

So the best solution is to use the Unity Decal system. It is similar to using texture but is an in built system that uses Unity shaders system. It would be more efficient then making a lot of gameobjects that contain a material.
The way you use it depends on what is the main render pipeline your using. Either Universal Render Pipeline (URP) or High Definition Render Pipeline (HDRP). Links to guides can be found bellow. Make sure to use the appropiate image of bullet holes when
Universal Render Pipeline (URP)
Decal Rendering in URP
High Definition Render Pipeline (HDRP)

just in addition for URP here is the official feature https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.0/manual/renderer-feature-decal.html

Good point. Just added it to the list,
